# Make a spinner stop and render the content after DOM loaded in vue

Tags: vue.js

I make a spinner component in my project and I pass some props to load the spinner and it's like this

```js
Vue.component("Spinner", require("./components/Loading/Loading.vue").default, {
    props: ["loading"]
});
```

```css
.spinner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index: 999;
}




.ring {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="spinner">
        <div class="ring">
            <half-circle-spinner :size="60" color="#1ABC9C"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and I call it in the other components like this:

```html
<template>




<Spinner key="list-key" :loading="true"/>




</template>
```

The thing I need is to make `this.spin = false` when all the DOM elements are loaded on my page. please let me know your ideas. :)

Comment: if the spinner is for the page itself you can hide it in `mounted` with `$nextTick`. if the spinner is like a plugin which the parent inform when data is loaded. then you can just use `v-if` in the parent which use the spinner

Comment: Thank you it was helpful... Just one more thing. Should I use it with mounted? Shouldn't I use it with any other lifecycles?

Comment: `mounted` is after dom render. but not guarantee that all child components also mounted that why you should use `$nextTick` the other lifecycles not fit for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll initialize a `isLoading` variable to true when the component is created and then set it to false in the `mounted` hook - by using `nextTick` in the mounted hook it will execute after all dom children have been loaded: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

You can try using `v-if` & `v-else` to show/hide the content/spinner based on a data attribute (such as `isLoading`) you can change once the content has loaded:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Spinner v-if="isLoading"/>
    <div v-else>
      ... actual dom content
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        isLoading: true
      }
    },

    mounted () {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.isLoading = false
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm actually searching for a way to make isLoading state false after DOM rendered!

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a way to make `isLoading` false after the DOM has rendered 

Comment: very well Thank you